# Flash Player behaviour when lost focus

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

I've got a real problem with FlashPlayer. What I need is to have it working on full speed when it is in the THROTTLE mode - that means when FlashPlayer loose its focus and decrease framerate to about 4fps. This is commonly know as a feature for mobile phones or when you change a tab in your browser and your .swf movie doesn't run with full speed anymore. 
I need this full speed because we run tests with flash swfs on virtual servers, and unfortunatelly tests run very long. 
I found that in FP11.2 was ThrottleEvent introduced that inform you what Flash Player is doing. It can go to PAUSE, THROTTLE, or RESUME state. Unfortunatelly it seems that I can't force other stage.frameRate when it really goes into any of these states. I tried also with Event.DEACTIVATE, and Event.ACTIVATE without any results.
Can I go around this any way? Or if not, what version of FlashPlayer was the latest before Adobe incorporated this feature into FP?
Thanks for any response!
Kindest Pawel

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701121/flash-player-stops-animating-when-out-of-viewport I was having the same issues. Turns out its not possible to disable this.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
stage.addEventListener(ThrottleEvent.THROTTLE, doStuff)
```