# Where can we find specs for Chrome's Flash Pausing?

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, flash

Google's upcoming release of Chrome will automatically pause Flash content it deems unimportant.

http://chrome.blogspot.com/2015/06/better-battery-life-for-your-laptop.html

They say they've worked with Adobe on this feature, yet I can find no information from Adobe about this.

Will we get some type of event, similar to the Throttle event, to let us know when Chrome has paused our content?  What will cause content to be considered unimportant?

Comment: As a workaround, listen to `Event.ENTER_FRAME` on your stage, and track `getTimer()` difference between consecutive frames. If it becomes too large, consider your app throttled down. There is, however, a `ThrottleEvent` class with events described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701121/flash-player-stops-animating-when-out-of-viewport), there are pause and resume events depicted.

Comment: Both of those case would mix instances where Flash was paused by Chrome in with instances of the player getting throttled because the Flash Player is not in the viewport.  A dedicated event would clear things up.